# Google sheets API - delete all spreadsheets from a sheet

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to delete all spreadsheets (leaving out the obligatory first sheet for the moment) from a sheets document at once. I only found a [way](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletesheetrequest) to delete single sheets from the spreadsheet. But as I have many sheets in the document, I run into API quota problems ([see limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits)).

[Problem visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWapS.png)

**Solution:**

Create a request that holds all spreadsheets that should be deleted. Then do a [batch update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). The spreadsheets have to be found in a former execution (not shown here). The request I used:

```js
const deleteSpreadsheetsRequest = {
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheet,
  resource: {
    requests: [
    ],
  },
};

// Starting @ i=1 because we can't delete all sheets in the spreadsheet
for (let i = 1; i < Sheets.length; i++) {
  deleteSpreadsheetsRequest.resource.requests.push({
    deleteSheet: {
      sheetId: Sheets[i].properties.sheetId,
    },
  });
}

await sheetClient.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(deleteSpreadsheetsRequest);
```

Comment: Do you mean 'delete spreadsheet' or 'delet sheet' ?

Comment: From `I want to delete all spreadsheets from a sheets document at once.` and `I only found a way to delete single Sheets from the spreadsheet.`, if you wanted to delete all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet, unfortunately, this cannot be achieved. Because, at least, it is required to have one sheet in a Google Spreadsheet. This is the current specification. I apologize for this. If you want to delete all sheets except for one sheet in a Google Spreadsheet, this can be achieved. But from your question, I couldn't understand the language you want to use. So, I commented on this.

Comment: I corrected the answer. Yes you are right. The first one has to remain. That's ok. I overwrite the one with data in the next run. But I'm on 120 spreadsheets that I want to get rid of. At the moment I delete 119 spreadsheets in a loop and the refill the sheet with new spreadsheets. I want to avoid that loop because it's time I need in my cloud function... But thanks for the comment! @MikeSteelson I meant delete spreadsheet. As I understood it right there cant be multiple spreadsheets in a sheet (according to the wording in the Google docs).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. And also, I couldn't understand `I want to avoid that loop because it's time I need in my cloud function...`.

Comment: I've added a picture. I hope that makes it clearer. But I think I found the solution. I have to make a batch update with a request that list all the Spreadsheets I want to delete. I will put the solution under the answer.

Comment: Thank you for repling and adding more information. From your additional information, I understood that you wanted to delete all sheets except for the 1st sheet using googleapis for Node.js. For this, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and my proposed modified script was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

From your following sample image, I thought that you wanted to delete all sheets except for the 1st sheet using googleapis for Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const sheetClient = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please use your "sheetClient".
const spreadsheet = "###"; // Please set Spreadsheet ID.

const obj = (
  await sheetClient.spreadsheets.get({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheet,
    fields: "sheets(properties(sheetId))",
  })
).data;
const requests = obj.sheets.reduce((ar, { properties: { sheetId } }, i) => {
  if (i > 0) {
    ar.push({ deleteSheet: { sheetId } });
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
const deleteSpreadsheetsRequest = {
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheet,
  resource: { requests },
};
await sheetClient.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(deleteSpreadsheetsRequest);
```

- In this modification, first, the sheet IDs are retrieved from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet. And, create an object for requesting Sheets API. And, request Sheets API using the created request body.
- When this script is run, all sheets except for the 1st sheet are deleted from a Google Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)